# Creating string from hash values

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash that looks like this:

```
{ 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => ['value2', 'value3']}
```

And I need to create a string that will look like this:

```
key1/value1;key2/value2,value3
```

So, the pattern is key/value and `';'` as separator. And if there are more than one value do value1,value2 `','` is the separator.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def build_string params
        url_params = ''
      params.each do |key, value|
        url_params += key
        url_params += '/'
        if value.kind_of? Array
          url_params += value.join(",") 
        else
          url_params += value
        end
        url_params += ';'
      end
      return url_params
    end
```

The problem is that this is adding a ';' at the end of the string, and I just want it as separator of each hash element. I have thought of doing a `join(';')`, but I am not sure how to do the rest of the operations beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
params.map { |k, v| "#{k}/#{[v].flatten.join(',')}" }.join(';')
```